# Improper result of Mergesort program

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, sorting, merge

I am making an attempt to implement the Mergesort program which works with Array of n element as followed. In this program, instead of making two separate arrays `L` and `R` which contains all numbers of array `a` on the left and right sides, I tried to cut it down to one array which have an equivalent number of elements as array `a`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 1000

void merge(int a[], int l, int m, int r) {
    int i, j, k = 0; 
    int b[r + 1];
    for (i = m; i >= 0; i--)
        b[i] = a[i]; 
    for (j = m + 1; j < r; j++) 
        b[r + m - j] = a[j]; 
    while (i <= m && j > m) { 
        if (b[i] <= b[j]) { 
            a[k] = b[i];
            i++; 
        } else { 
            a[k] = b[j];
            j--; 
        } 
        k++; 
    }
    while (i <= m) { 
        a[k] = b[i];
        i++;
        k++; 
    } 
    while (j > m) { 
        a[k] = b[j];
        j--;
        k++; 
    } 
} 

void mergesort(int a[], int l, int r) {
    int i, j, k, mid;
    int b[r + 1];
    if (r > l) {
        mid = (l + r) / 2;
        mergesort(a, l, mid);
        mergesort(a, mid + 1, r);
        merge(a, l, mid, r);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    int i = 0;
    int a[MAX];
    printf("Enter the number of element you want to create: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (i < n) {
        printf("Enter your number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    mergesort(a, 0, n);
    i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, it gave me improper result and I don't know where I get wrong.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the second loop in `merge()` is sending things askew: `for (j = m+1; j < r; j++) 
        b[r+m-j] = a[j];` is probably writing to the wrong places. (I think it copies the elements in the upper half of the array into `b` in the reverse order — but I'm willing to be proved wrong on that; I've only done the analysis mentally, not with a compiler).  I'm not sure why you don't simply use `for (int i = l; i < r; i++) b[i] = a[i];` and then copy the right elements from `b` back into `a` in the merged order.

Comment: For the right part I need  to copy all elements from ``r`` to ``m`` to the array ``b`` but the array ``a`` still from ``m`` to ``r``

Comment: How have you tried to debug the code?  I added printing code to print the arrays on entry to and exit from `merge()` and `mergesort()`, and the `merge()` function generated lists of `1` rather than the values supplied in the original data (all my values were in the range `10`..`99`).  I find the `merge()` function as written to be completely counter-intuitive.  It is simply not written the way my mind works.  For my money, you should rewrite it entirely.  (I'm tolerably certain the `merge()` function is reading and/or writing out of bounds, too.)

Comment: Amongst other problems, when you first enter the loop `while (i<=m && j>m)` in `merge()`, `i` is less than 0 (`-1`), and `m` is equal to `r`.  Consequently, the first comparison is accessing the array out of bounds.  The first `for` loop shouldn't be counting down to `0` either; it should be counting down to `l`.  There are many problems in that `merge()` function, as I already stated.

Comment: Use the algorithm from the "related" section: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274947/mergesort-algorithm-implementation?rq=1 It has a correct algorithm. In particular, it does _not_ use reverse indexing.

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat:* For speed/tiredness, I borrowed the `merge` from the link I mentioned in my top comments and cleaned it up a bit.

And, I renamed the variables to more closely match yours.

It matches merge functions I've written before.

One difference is that it does the copyback operation from `b` to `a` at the end, rather than doing a copyin operation from `a` to `b` at the start.

And, as I mentioned above, it doesn't traverse arrays in a negative direction [I've not seen that approach before].

Further, the temp array `b` always indexes starting from 0, regardless of the values of `l`, `m`, or `r`. This simpilifies things a bit.

For debugging, I changed `main` a bit to make it do an automatic worst case test and did a sort check at the end, along with some debug `printf`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 1000

void
merge(int a[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    static int b[MAX];
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    printf("merge: ENTER l=%d m=%d r=%d\n",l,m,r);

    k = 0;
    i = l;
    j = m + 1;

    for (;  (i <= m) && (j <= r);  ++k) {
        if (a[i] <= a[j])
            b[k] = a[i++];
        else
            b[k] = a[j++];
    }

    for (;  i <= m;  ++i, ++k)
        b[k] = a[i];

    for (;  j <= r;  ++j, ++k)
        b[k] = a[j];

    k = 0;
    for (i = l;  i <= r;  ++i, ++k)
        a[i] = b[k];

    printf("merge: EXIT\n");
}

void
merge_original(int a[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i,
     j,
     k = 0;

    printf("merge: ENTER l=%d m=%d r=%d\n",l,m,r);

#if 1
    int b[r + 1];
    for (i = m; i >= 0; i--)
        b[i] = a[i];
#endif

    for (j = m + 1; j < r; j++)
        b[r + m - j] = a[j];

    while (i <= m && j > m) {
        if (b[i] <= b[j]) {
            a[k] = b[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            a[k] = b[j];
            j--;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (i <= m) {
        a[k] = b[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j > m) {
        a[k] = b[j];
        j--;
        k++;
    }

    printf("merge: EXIT\n");
}

void
mergesort(int a[], int l, int r)
{
    int i,
     j,
     k,
     mid;
    int b[r + 1];

    if (r > l) {
        mid = (l + r) / 2;
        mergesort(a, l, mid);
        mergesort(a, mid + 1, r);
        merge(a, l, mid, r);
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    int n;
    int i;
    int a[MAX];

    printf("Enter the number of element you want to create: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0;  i < n;   ++i) {
#if 0
        printf("Enter your number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
#else
        a[i] = n - i;
#endif
        printf("SET %d: %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    mergesort(a, 0, n);

    int oval = -1;
    int cval;
    for (i = 0;  i < n;   ++i, oval = cval) {
        cval = a[i];

        printf("CMP %d: %d\n", i, cval);

        if (cval < oval) {
            printf("fault\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I have a question that in the `merge` function, what is the function of the third `for` loop here?

Note that [in *both* your code and the updated code] `b` is the temp array.

There are four loops in total:

(1) The "merge" loop [which takes the lowest of either subarray while *both* subarrays still have remaining elements]:

```
for (;  (i <= m) && (j <= r);  ++k)
```

(2) The second loop copies any elements in the low/left subarray into the destination *if* it has more remaining elements than the high/right subarray:

```
for (;  i <= m;  ++i, ++k)
```

(3) The third loop copies any elements in the high/right subarray into the destination *if* it has more remaining elements than the low/left subarray:

```
for (;  j <= r;  ++j, ++k)
```

(4) The fourth loop copies from the [temp] array `b` back into the original array `a`:

```
for (i = l;  i <= r;  ++i, ++k)
```

Note that only *one* of loop (2) or loop (3) will actually copy data. That's because loop (1) has guaranteed that either `i <= m` *or* `j <= r` will be *false* after it is done.

In your original code, your first two loops [merely] copy from the low/high subarrays within `a` into `b`. Then, you merge from `b` back into `a` [in three loops].

In the modified code, we merge from `a` into `b` [in the first three loops]. Then, we copy back from the [temp] `b` array into `a`.

So, we must use a temp array. But, we can copy into it at the start. *Or*, we can copy out of it at the end. Either approach will work.

And remember that I mentioned that the `b` array was being indexed from zero. This allowed one less loop (four vs. five)

Comment: I have a question that in the ``merge`` function, what is the function of the third ``for`` loop here?

Answer (score 1):

This code shows how I instrumented the algorithm.  Initially, it was done with unconditional calls to `printf()` and `dump_array()` — when it was working, they were converted to the macros so that the code could be compiled with `-DDEBUG` to get a detailed trace or without to just get the result.

I didn't remove the prompting code, but my own programs wouldn't do that.  I'd probably also have the program count how many values are input (using dynamic memory allocation to make room for the data) and simply read data until it reaches EOF.  For testing, I used three sets of randomly generated numbers saved in files so that the tests were repeatable.

I've not attempted to fix the original `merge()` code — I've simply rewritten it.  My comments to the question outline some of the issues with the original code.  I'm fairly sure that the code in the question doesn't pay sufficient attention to which ranges of numbers are valid.  This code annotates that the ranges to `mergesort()` and `merge()` are inclusive of the end indexes (hence `main()` calls `mergesort(a, 0, n - 1)` rather than `mergesort(a, 0, n)` as in the question, for example).

This merge code copies the data into the `b` array first and then merges from `b` back to `a` (more or less like the code in the question) — it would be feasible to merge into `b` and then copy from `b` to `a` again.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000

#ifdef DEBUG
#define TRACE(...)          printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DUMP(t, a, l, r)    dump_array(t, a, l, r)
#else
#define TRACE(...)          ((void)0)
#define DUMP(t, a, l, r)    ((void)0)
#endif

/* Dump elements in range l <= i <= r */
static void dump_array(const char *tag, int a[], int l, int r)
{
    assert(tag != 0 && a != 0 && l >= 0 && l <= r);
    printf("%s[%d..%d]:", tag, l, r);
    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
        printf(" %d", a[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

/* Merge elements in ranges l <= i <= m and m+1 <= j <= r */
static void merge(int a[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    assert(a != 0 && l >= 0 && l <= m && m <= r);
    TRACE("-->> %s(): %d..%d..%d\n", __func__, l, m, r);
    int b[r + 1];
    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
        b[i] = a[i];
    DUMP("b", b, l, r);
    int k = l;
    int i = l;
    int j = m + 1;
    while (i <= m && j <= r)
    {
        if (b[i] <= b[j])
            a[k++] = b[i++];
        else
            a[k++] = b[j++];
    }
    while (i <= m)
        a[k++] = b[i++];
    while (j <= r)
        a[k++] = b[j++];
    DUMP("a", a, l, r);
    TRACE("<<-- %s(): %d..%d..%d\n", __func__, l, m, r);
}

/* Sort elements in range l <= i <= r */
static void mergesort(int a[], int l, int r)
{
    assert(a != 0 && l >= 0 && l <= r);
    if (r > l)
    {
        TRACE("-->> %s(): %d..%d\n", __func__, l, r);
        DUMP("a", a, l, r);
        int mid = (l + r) / 2;
        mergesort(a, l, mid);
        DUMP("a", a, l, mid);
        mergesort(a, mid + 1, r);
        DUMP("a", a, mid+1, r);
        merge(a, l, mid, r);
        DUMP("a", a, l, r);
        TRACE("<<-- %s(): %d..%d\n", __func__, l, r);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    int a[MAX];
    printf("Enter the number of elements you want to create: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 1 || n > MAX)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "read error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter your number %d: ", i);
        if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "read error\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');

    dump_array("Unsorted", a, 0, n - 1);
    mergesort(a, 0, n - 1);
    dump_array("Sorted", a, 0, n - 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Example run (`-DDEBUG`; data set of 5 elements — which are printed, of course, to allow checking):

```
Enter the number of elements you want to create: Enter your number 0: Enter your number 1: Enter your number 2: Enter your number 3: Enter your number 4: 
Unsorted[0..4]: 17 74 63 62 26
-->> mergesort(): 0..4
a[0..4]: 17 74 63 62 26
-->> mergesort(): 0..2
a[0..2]: 17 74 63
-->> mergesort(): 0..1
a[0..1]: 17 74
a[0..0]: 17
a[1..1]: 74
-->> merge(): 0..0..1
b[0..1]: 17 74
a[0..1]: 17 74
<<-- merge(): 0..0..1
a[0..1]: 17 74
<<-- mergesort(): 0..1
a[0..1]: 17 74
a[2..2]: 63
-->> merge(): 0..1..2
b[0..2]: 17 74 63
a[0..2]: 17 63 74
<<-- merge(): 0..1..2
a[0..2]: 17 63 74
<<-- mergesort(): 0..2
a[0..2]: 17 63 74
-->> mergesort(): 3..4
a[3..4]: 62 26
a[3..3]: 62
a[4..4]: 26
-->> merge(): 3..3..4
b[3..4]: 62 26
a[3..4]: 26 62
<<-- merge(): 3..3..4
a[3..4]: 26 62
<<-- mergesort(): 3..4
a[3..4]: 26 62
-->> merge(): 0..2..4
b[0..4]: 17 63 74 26 62
a[0..4]: 17 26 62 63 74
<<-- merge(): 0..2..4
a[0..4]: 17 26 62 63 74
<<-- mergesort(): 0..4
Sorted[0..4]: 17 26 62 63 74
```

Sample run (`-UDEBUG` with 12 elements — the 5-element set uses the first 5 numbers from this set):

```
Enter the number of elements you want to create: Enter your number 0: Enter your number 1: Enter your number 2: Enter your number 3: Enter your number 4: Enter your number 5: Enter your number 6: Enter your number 7: Enter your number 8: Enter your number 9: Enter your number 10: Enter your number 11: 
Unsorted[0..11]: 17 74 63 62 26 16 15 86 80 17 35 69
Sorted[0..11]: 15 16 17 17 26 35 62 63 69 74 80 86
```

Sample run (`-UDEBUG` with 30 elements — a separate set of random numbers altogether):

```
Enter the number of elements you want to create: Enter your number 0: Enter your number 1: Enter your number 2: Enter your number 3: Enter your number 4: Enter your number 5: Enter your number 6: Enter your number 7: Enter your number 8: Enter your number 9: Enter your number 10: Enter your number 11: Enter your number 12: Enter your number 13: Enter your number 14: Enter your number 15: Enter your number 16: Enter your number 17: Enter your number 18: Enter your number 19: Enter your number 20: Enter your number 21: Enter your number 22: Enter your number 23: Enter your number 24: Enter your number 25: Enter your number 26: Enter your number 27: Enter your number 28: Enter your number 29: 
Unsorted[0..29]: 80 76 86 10 46 99 12 55 76 34 86 23 76 83 13 21 93 50 19 53 86 92 81 35 90 53 65 67 79 20
Sorted[0..29]: 10 12 13 19 20 21 23 34 35 46 50 53 53 55 65 67 76 76 76 79 80 81 83 86 86 86 90 92 93 99
```

I did a check on the 30-element set — taking the list of unsorted numbers, sorting them with `sort -n`, and comparing that list with the sorted output.  The result was identical, which means that the 'sorted order' and 'conservation' properties of a sort were valid.  I eyeballed the results for the sets of 5 and 12 data values.