# 'MergeSort Algorithm' - What's the better implementation in JAVA?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, optimization, mergesort

I know quick sort algorithm, but I am concerned with merge sort algorithm only.

I found out on internet two types of merge sort algorithm implementation.
But when I compare them with insertion algorithm, they seem less efficient and this is not expected for a large number of items.

```
Enter the number of elements you want to sort:
300000

Time spent to executing BubbleSort: 362123 milliseconds
Time spent to executing Selection:  108285 milliseconds
Time spent to executing Insertion:   18046 milliseconds
Time spent to executing MergeSort:   35968 milliseconds
Time spent to executing MergeSort2:  35823 milliseconds
```

Is there another way to implement the merge sort algorithm to make it more efficient than the insertion algorithm?

Take a look at my code...

```
package br.com.test.test1;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

 /**
 *
 * @author Joao
 */
public class Main {

    // generate an int array with random numbers between 0 and 500
    public static int[] generateRand(int n){
        int[] randArray = new int[n];
        Random number = new Random();

        // random numbers between 0 and 500
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            randArray[i] = number.nextInt(501);
        }
        return randArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;

        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements you want to sort:");
        n = input.nextInt();

        MyArray array = new MyArray(n);
        int[] aux = new int[n];
        aux = generateRand(n);


        array.copy(aux);   
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        array.bubblesort();
        // Time spent to executing BUBBLESORT 
        System.out.println("\nTime spent to executing BubbleSort: "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)+" milliseconds");


        array.copy(aux);   
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        array.selection();
        // Time spent to executing SELECTION 
        System.out.println("Time spent to executing Selection: "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)+" milliseconds");


        array.copy(aux);   
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        array.insertion();
        // Time spent to executing INSERTION 
        System.out.println("Time spent to executing Insertion: "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)+" milliseconds");


        array.copy(aux);   
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        array.mergeSort(0, n-1);
        // Time spent to executing MERGESORT 
        System.out.println("Time spent to executing MergeSort: "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)+" milliseconds");


        array.copy(aux);   
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        array.mergeSort2(0, n-1);
        // Time spent to executing MERGESORT 2
        System.out.println("Time spent to executing MergeSort2: "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)+" milliseconds");

    }
}
```

---- and ------

```
package br.com.test.test1;

/**
 *
 * @author Joao Paulo
 */
class MyArray {
    private int[] v;
    private int n;  // array index
    private int len;

    public MyArray(int length) {
        len = length;
        v = new int[len];
        n = 0;
    }

    public void copy(int[] k){
        n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            v[i] = k[i];
            n++;
        }
    }

    public void show(){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + v[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }


    // *******  START OF ALGORITHMS TO SORT  *******

    // ----------   Start of BubbleSort and Selection   --------------
    public void bubblesort(){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++) {
                if (v[j] > v[j+1]) {
                    change(j, j+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void selection() {
        int min;
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            min = i;
            for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++){
                if (v[j] < v[min]){
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            change(i, min);
        }
    }

    private void change(int one, int two) {
        int temp = v[one];
        v[one] = v[two];
        v[two] = temp;
    }
    // ----------   End of BubbleSort and Selection   ----------------


    // ----------   Start of Insertion   -----------------------------
    public void insertion() {
        int i, j;
        int temp;
        for (i=1; i < n; i++) {
            temp = v[i];   // marked variable
            j = i;
            while ((j > 0) && (v[j-1] > temp)) {
                v[j] = v[j-1];
                j = j - 1;
            }
            v[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    // ----------   End of Insertion   -------------------------------


    // ----------   Start of MergeSort   -----------------------------
    public void mergeSort (int start, int end){
        if(start == end) return;

        int middle = (start+end)/2;
        mergeSort(start,middle);
        mergeSort(middle+1,end);
        merge(start,middle,end);
    }

    public void merge(int start, int middle, int end) {
        int[] aux = new int[v.length];

        for (int x = start; x <= end; x++) {
            aux[x] = v[x];
        }

        int i = start;
        int j = middle+1;
        int k = start;

        //emptying out array 'v' inserting items neatly in array 'aux' 
        while (i <= middle && j <= end) {
            if (aux[i] < aux[j]){
                v[k++] = aux[i++];
            } else {
                v[k++] = aux[j++];
            }
        }

        //copying values from 'aux' to 'v'
        while (i <= middle){
            v[k++] = aux[i++];
        }

        while (j <= end){
            v[k++] = aux[j++];
        }
    }
    // ----------   End of MergeSort   -------------------------------


    // ----------   Start of MergeSort 2  ----------------------------
    public void mergeSort2 (int start, int end) {
        if(start >= end) return;

        int middle = (start+end)/2;
        mergeSort2(start,middle);
        mergeSort2(middle+1,end);
        merge2(start,middle,end);
    }

    public void merge2(int start, int middle, int end) {
        int[] helper = new int[v.length];

        // Copy both parts into the helper array
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            helper[i] = v[i];
        }

        int i = start;
        int j = middle + 1;
        int k = start;

        // Copy the smallest values from either the left or the right side back to the original array
        while (i <= middle && j <= end) {
            if (helper[i] <= helper[j]) {
                v[k] = helper[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                v[k] = helper[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        // Copy the rest of the left side of the array into the target array
        while (i <= middle) {
            v[k] = helper[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        // Since we are sorting in-place any leftover elements from the right side
        // are already at the right position.
    }
    // ----------   End of MergeSort 2  ------------------------------

}
```

Comment: If the code is working, the the Code Review Stack Exchange is the place to ask this question.

Comment: [Understanding merge sort optimization: avoiding copies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577825/understanding-merge-sort-optimization-avoiding-copies). [Combining MergeSort with Insertion sort to make it more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057287/combining-mergesort-with-insertion-sort-to-make-it-more-efficient) / [Combining merge sort and insertion sort](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/68179/combining-merge-sort-and-insertion-sort).

Comment: Your mergesorts are slow because you're allocating a new array in every recursive call.  You should only allocate one temporary array.

Comment: Note - I did minor format clean up of the example programs in my answer. The actual code was not changed, just the formatting and some comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview instead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - did you miss the part of the question: `Is there another way to implement the merge sort algorithm to make it more efficient ... ?` . The question appears to be asking for alternative solutions, not a code review.

Comment: @rcgldr That would actually bring this question in the "too broad" area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a single allocation of the working/temp array and avoid copying of data during merge (unless moving a single remaining run from one array to the other).

Bottom up merge sort example.

```
package jsortbu;
import java.util.Random;

public class jsortbu {
    static void MergeSort(int[] a)          // entry function
    {
        if(a.length < 2)                    // if size < 2 return
            return;
        int[] b = new int[a.length];
        BottomUpMergeSort(a, b);
    }

    static void BottomUpMergeSort(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
    int n = a.length;
    int s = 1;                              // run size 
        if(1 == (GetPassCount(n)&1)){       // if odd number of passes
            for(s = 1; s < n; s += 2)       // swap in place for 1st pass
                if(a[s] < a[s-1]){
                    int t = a[s];
                    a[s] = a[s-1];
                    a[s-1] = t;
                }
            s = 2;
        }
        while(s < n){                       // while not done
            int ee = 0;                     // reset end index
            while(ee < n){                  // merge pairs of runs
                int ll = ee;                // ll = start of left  run
                int rr = ll+s;              // rr = start of right run
                if(rr >= n){                // if only left run
                    do{                     //   copy it
                        b[ll] = a[ll];
                        ll++;
                    }while(ll < n);
                    break;                  //   end of pass
                }
                ee = rr+s;                  // ee = end of right run
                if(ee > n)
                    ee = n;
                Merge(a, b, ll, rr, ee);
            }
            {                               // swap references
                int[] t = a;
                a = b;
                b = t;
            }
            s <<= 1;                        // double the run size
        }
    }

    static void Merge(int[] a, int[] b, int ll, int rr, int ee) {
        int o = ll;                         // b[]       index
        int l = ll;                         // a[] left  index
        int r = rr;                         // a[] right index
        while(true){                        // merge data
            if(a[l] <= a[r]){               // if a[l] <= a[r]
                b[o++] = a[l++];            //   copy a[l]
                if(l < rr)                  //   if not end of left run
                    continue;               //     continue (back to while)
                while(r < ee){              //   else copy rest of right run
                    b[o++] = a[r++];
                }
                break;                      //     and return
            } else {                        // else a[l] > a[r]
                b[o++] = a[r++];            //   copy a[r]
                if(r < ee)                  //   if not end of right run
                    continue;               //     continue (back to while)
                while(l < rr){              //   else copy rest of left run
                    b[o++] = a[l++];
                }
                break;                      //     and return
            }
        }
    }

    static int GetPassCount(int n)          // return # passes
    {
        int i = 0;
        for(int s = 1; s < n; s <<= 1)
            i += 1;
        return(i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[10000000];
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            a[i] = r.nextInt();
        long bgn, end;
        bgn = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MergeSort(a);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++){
            if(a[i-1] > a[i]){
                System.out.println("failed");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("milliseconds " + (end-bgn));
    }
}
```

Top down merge sort example. A pair of mutually recursive functions are used to avoid copy back operations. The direction of merge is based on the level of recursion. Merge() is the same for both bottom up and top down.

```
package jsorttd;
import java.util.Random;

public class jsorttd {
    static void MergeSort(int[] a)          // entry function
    {
        if(a.length < 2)                    // if size < 2 return
            return;
        int[] b = new int[a.length];
        MergeSortAtoA(a, b, 0, a.length);
    }

    static void MergeSortAtoA(int[] a, int[] b, int ll, int ee)
    {
        if(ee - ll > 1) {
            int rr = (ll + ee)>>1;          // midpoint, start of right half
            MergeSortAtoB(a, b, ll, rr);
            MergeSortAtoB(a, b, rr, ee);
            Merge(b, a, ll, rr, ee);        // merge b to a
        }
    }

    static void MergeSortAtoB(int[] a, int[] b, int ll, int ee)
    {
        if(ee - ll > 1) {
            int rr = (ll + ee)>>1;          //midpoint, start of right half
            MergeSortAtoA(a, b, ll, rr);
            MergeSortAtoA(a, b, rr, ee);
            Merge(a, b, ll, rr, ee);        // merge a to b
        } else if((ee - ll) == 1) {         // if just one element
            b[ll] = a[ll];                  //   copy a to b
        }
    }

    static void Merge(int[] a, int[] b, int ll, int rr, int ee) {
        int o = ll;                         // b[]       index
        int l = ll;                         // a[] left  index
        int r = rr;                         // a[] right index
        while(true){                        // merge data
            if(a[l] <= a[r]){               // if a[l] <= a[r]
                b[o++] = a[l++];            //   copy a[l]
                if(l < rr)                  //   if not end of left run
                    continue;               //     continue (back to while)
                while(r < ee){              //   else copy rest of right run
                    b[o++] = a[r++];
                }
                break;                      //     and return
            } else {                        // else a[l] > a[r]
                b[o++] = a[r++];            //   copy a[r]
                if(r < ee)                  //   if not end of right run
                    continue;               //     continue (back to while)
                while(l < rr){              //   else copy rest of left run
                    b[o++] = a[l++];
                }
                break;                      //     and return
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[10000000];
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            a[i] = r.nextInt();
        long bgn, end;
        bgn = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MergeSort(a);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++){
            if(a[i-1] > a[i]){
                System.out.println("failed");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("milliseconds " + (end-bgn));
     }
}
```

Both methods take about 1 second to sort 10 million integers on my system (Win 7, Intel 3770K 3.5 ghz, NetBeans 8.1, Java 1.8.0_65-b17).